# Web Deployment Task Failed - FRAMEWORK VERSIONS DO NOT MATCH

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy

When I try to use web deploy to publish my app. I get this error

```
Web deployment task failed. (The versions of the .NET Framework Configuration Provider (machineConfig32) are different on the source (4.0) and destination (2.0).  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FRAMEWORK_VERSIONS_DO_NOT_MATCH.)
```

I went to this page and did #2 under ERROR_FRAMEWORK_VERSIONS_DO_NOT_MATCH

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes.

Restarted the service and I continue to still get the error.

Please help.

UPDATE:

Ran

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:machineConfig32 -dest:machineConfig32,computerName=10.10.10.10 -disableSkipDirective:ConfigProtectedData
```

and got

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:machine
Config32 -dest:machineConfig32,computerName=10.10.10.10 -disableSkipDirective:Con
figProtectedData 
Info: Using ID '0998ab97-343f-4338-8f74-ceaf614ea0d1' for connections to the rem
ote server.
Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes c
opied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is written in a newer version of .Net (4.0) than the version that is installed on the server (2.0). You will probably need to **update the server to .Net 4.0**.

Here are instructions on [how to install 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851). Basically, you just download the code and run it.

Different versions of .Net can run side by side on the same machine.

If you have issues with having the server connected to the internet for the install, you can get some guidance [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/132122/is-there-a-net-4-0-offline-install).

**Edit:** [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) specifically addresses the .NET Framework Configuration Provider and the changes needed for 4.0.

Comment: Did you set the specific site to .net 4?

Answer (score 0):

Try Skipping AppPool sync. May be your application AppPool is configured to use different version of Asp.Net on both source and destination server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was going absolutely crazy trying to resolve it.  Release worked fine but I could not do a Debug deploy.  I definitely has .Net 4 in both environments.  Finally, I turned on warnings and noticed a message that indicated that 2 deployment parameters were specified that should not be used together.  I went to Properties > Package/Publish Web and unchecked "**Include IIS settings as configured in IIS Express**".  Viola!  What a PITA.